# Does a potential of interaction produce also torque?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, potential-energy

I have a system of particles (spheres with masses and radii), with $6$ degree of freedom (they are free to move and rotate). Between each couple there is an interaction potential $V(\vec{d})$, where $\vec{d} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is the distance between the centers of the particles considered.

It is well-known that particle $i$ will experience a force from $j$ in the form $\vec{F}_{ij} = -\nabla V(\vec{d}_{ij})$.

Particles are also subject to friction ($\lambda$ is the friction coefficient). The ODEs regulating the position is:

$$\begin{cases}
\displaystyle \ddot{x}_i = -\frac{\lambda}{m_i}\dot{x}_i + \sum_{j \neq i}\frac{F_{ijx}}{m_i}\\
\displaystyle \ddot{y}_i = -\frac{\lambda}{m_i}\dot{y}_i + \sum_{j \neq i}\frac{F_{ijy}}{m_i}\\
\displaystyle \ddot{z}_i = -\frac{\lambda}{m_i}\dot{z}_i + \sum_{j \neq i}\frac{F_{ijz}}{m_i}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Given $\vec{\theta}_i$ the vector of the rotational state variables of the particle $i$, and $I$ its moment of inertia,  how can I write the laws of rotation?

$$
\begin{cases}
I_i \ddot{\theta}_{i,x} = \ldots\\
I_i \ddot{\theta}_{i,y} = \ldots\\
I_i \ddot{\theta}_{i,z} = \ldots
\end{cases}
$$

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by "*rotational variables*"? spherical coordinates?

Comment: yeah, I'm sorry. I mean zenith and azimuth